# Show that $\sqrt{t}\sum_{n=0}^\infty N(n)e^{-n\pi t} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} \sum_{n=0}^\infty N(n) e^{\frac{-n \pi}{t}} $

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

As the title reads, a homework problem in fourier analysis is to show the above equality.

The function
$N(n) = \{(n_1, n_2) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 : n_1^2 + n_2^2 = n\}$ is the number of points in $\mathbb{Z}^2 $ that have distance exactly $\sqrt{n}$ to the origin.

We are following the book fourier series and integrals by Dym & Mckean.

The book introduces the "theta function":
For $t>0 , \theta(t) = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{ +\infty} e^{-\pi n^2 t}$

I have tried to analyse this using the similar swindle used to prove the Jacobi theta function identity:(p52 in the book)
$\theta(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\theta(\frac{1}{t})$, however, I can not make any progress. Nor do I see where the properties of the function $N(n)$ are to be used. I am aware that there is a closed form expression of $N(n)$, nevetheless I was unable to use that in the setting of a fourier series.

Moreover, I am assuming that $t>0$ but this information is not given. Naturally the proposition holds for $t=1$. Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you stated the $\theta$ function property correctly? As it stands it has closed form solutions $0, \pm(t-1)^{-1}$, neither of which are theta functions. If it is a typo on your part, then it looks like you are being asked to prove the same thing again you proved with the $\theta$ function, with $$f(t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty N(n)e^{-n\pi t}$$

Comment: $\theta(t)^2 = ?$

Comment: Ninad Munshi , I made a mistake, it is now corrected. It should be $\theta(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\theta(\frac{1}{t})$.